# Enhanced New York State License with name not in proper order

Tags: usa, canada, international-travel, paperwork, driving-licenses

My brother received his Enhanced New York State driver's licence and his name is not displayed properly- (First name is where Last name should be - Middle name where First name should be and Last name where Middle name should be. There is a comma separating Middle and Last names however).

Is this document valid for entry into Canada and back into the United States, or must it be corrected to be valid? Checked with New York State D M V, but they could not furnish a definite answer. I could not contact either the U S or Canadian border Patrols for any clarification. We are traveling this coming Friday.

Comment: You mean something like this? Billy Bob Jones -> Bob Jones, Billy?

Comment: Is this the same license that you [cancelled](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91671/cancelled-enhanced-drivers-license)? Or are these two separate, but closely related, problems, one for you and one for your brother?

Comment: When you say "should be" are you taking into account the fact that NY licenses show names as *LAST* on the line above *FIRST, MIDDLE* (in other words, does your license say *FIRST* on the line above *MIDDLE, LAST?*  I suppose the names are also in that order in the machine readable zone on the back; are they?

Comment: Separate, but closely related. Should read Jones on first line then Billy,Bob on second line. License reads Billy on first line then Bob,Jones on second line.

Comment: Yes I am. However his has the first name where the last name should be, his middle name where his first name should be and his last name where his middle name should be. It is most likely that the application was not filled out correctly, and the clerk at the DMV copied what was on it, (and no one caught the error) until the permanent license arrived. And that is how the names are in the readable zone on the back.

Comment: Yes they are, First then Middle then Last in readable zone on back.

Comment: Well I think my comment to your other question also applies here, more or  less. As long as he has other proof of identity and citizenship, he may get a lecture from the officers at the border but he should be able to travel.  The chance of a thorough search and other delays at the border, such as the aforementioned lecture and perhaps waiting while documents are authenticated and database are checked, is significantly higher, though.

Comment: @phoog the two questions from OP have been open for a month, and your comments in both best respond to the concern; if you add them  as answers, I'll upvote.

Comment: @Dorothy done ([here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/93227/19400) and [there](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/93224/19400)).  But it looks like Ed is a hit-and-run.  I hope he will come back and answer the questions himself to report his experiences.  It was interesting to see that Canada seems to have deprecated its former advice that a birth certificate or similar document is useful, and more generally how sloppy their current information is ("...officer will ask to see your passport and a valid visa, if you are arriving from a country for which one is required.").

Comment: @phoog I know, like so many, unfortunately, and especially when they get such good and immediate responses.

Answer (score 2):

Please see my [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/93224/19400) to your [other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/91671/19400).  In general, Canada admits US citizens with any proof of identity and citizenship.  This should include an enhanced license with a clerical error.

In fact, when your brother shows the license, they may not even notice that the name is reversed.  But, if they do, he may want to be prepared with independent photographic proof of identity, if he has it, as well as his birth certificate.

To get back into the US, as noted in the other answer, he is nominally supposed to have one of several documents specified by the WHTI.  But in fact US citizens have a fundamental right to enter the country, so if he can prove his US citizenship by any means, such as a birth certificate, then CBP has to let him in.  "Any means" may well also include an enhanced driver's license with a clerical error.  The only caveat is that entry without a WHTI-specified document could take longer.  Your brother should be prepared for the possibility that he will have to spend some time in secondary inspection as CBP considers his evidence of US citizenship.